# I can't figure out how to list Phyton output as a list

Tags: python

> Write a Python program that requests the following three int values
>   from the user:
>   a starting number
>   a ending number
>   an increment size
>   Display all of the numbers, starting with the first value, up
>   to, but not including the second value, by incrementing by the third
>   value. Separate values with commas.  Do not include a comma after the
>   last number.  If the relationship between the starting and ending
>   values does not make sense given the increment size, then do not
>   display anything.

The code I created doesn't display them as commas. What I have is:

```
def main():
  startingNum = int(input("Please enter a starting number:"))
  endingNum = int(input("Please enter an ending number:"))
  incrementSize = int(input("Please enter an increment size:"))
  lastValue = endingNum - incrementSize
  print(startingNum)
  if startingNum < lastValue:
    while startingNum < lastValue:
      value = startingNum + incrementSize
      startingNum = startingNum + incrementSize
      print(value)
  else:
    while startingNum > lastValue:
      value = startingNum + incrementSize
      startingNum = startingNum + incrementSize
      print(value)
main()
```

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow! The focus of the site isn't to solve hw problems, so if you have a specific question about some issue I'd recommend editing your question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You just have to print str(value)+’,’